# Sylvester's criterion for negative semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

Is there a Sylvester's criterion for negative semidefinite matrices? 
I suspect such a criterion to be:

- All principal minors with odd dimension are non-positive.
- All principal minors with even dimension are non-negative.

Please include a reference if it exists.

Comment: This is indeed the case.  In order to prove it, simply apply the usual criterion to $-A$, where $A$ is *positive* semidefinite.  I have not seen this in a linear algebra text, but I know that this comes up in multivariate optimization problems (in the "second derivative test").

Comment: This is treated in Simon & Blume's Mathematics for Economists, page 383.

Comment: For a quick numerical check, it is also equivalent to: all the eigenvalues are $\le 0$. Or, the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial have the same sign ( think $a(x+1)(x+2) \ldots $ ).